# How can I mesure the axial induction factor of a small propeller using a DC motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I am trying to measure the axial induction factor of a small aeromodelling propeller.
By axial induction factor I call the ratio of the velocity of the wind far from the propeller $V_{\infty}$ over the velocity through the actuator disk $V_{d}$ as introduced in the Rankine-Froude actuator theory.

Let us call $$a=\frac{V_{d}}{V_{\infty}}$$ the induction factor.

The experimental setup is the following :

- The propeller is mounted on the axis of a DC motor
- Those are placed into a wind tunnel
- A resistance $R$ (of a value really close from the internal engine resistance) is connected to the poles of the DC motor and the voltage drop $U$ across the resistance is measured.

From the actuator theory we know that the mechanical power transmitted to the propeller can be expressed as :
$$P_{mech}=2\rho_{\infty}SV_{\infty}^2a^2(1-a)$$

Given that $S$ is the area of the actuator disk.
From the experimental setup supposing that the efficientcy of the DC engine is $\eta$ I have :
$$P_{elec}=2\frac{U^2}{R}=\eta P_{mech}$$

From this I can find :
$$a^2(1-a)=\frac{U^2}{R\eta\rho_{\infty}SV_{\infty}^2}$$

The issue is that the experiments do not provide a satisfying value for $a$, the values I find are really close to $a=1$ which wolud mean that the propeller does not have any impact on the flow even if it rotates really fast.

Are there any flaws either in my experimental setup or in my theory ?

Comment: Why not measure the actual velocity profile across the prop with a pitot tube?